# How to achieve circular UI in tab view android java

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am working on a project for a client and they gave me the UI where I have to implement a certain tab like layout and I was wondering how to achieve this kind of tab on android. I have attached the image below. Any help would be much appreciated.

The snapshot of what I want to achieve

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If you don't mind then this answer is not based on circular UI in tab view android java but it almost fulfills your need.

##### Output (please don't mind app name):

[image]

You can achieve your need by using this XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="#EDFAFF"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/personalInfoTab"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/radio_btn_checked"
    app:tint="@color/black" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/personalInfoProgress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="-4dp"
    android:max="100"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/personalInfoTab"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/personalInfoTab"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/personalInfoTab" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/paymentTab"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/personalInfoProgress"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/paymentProgressBar"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/personalInfoProgress"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/personalInfoProgress"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_circle_24"
    app:tint="#353535" />

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/paymentProgressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/paymentTab"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/confirmationTab"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/paymentTab" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/confirmationTab"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/paymentProgressBar"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/paymentProgressBar"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_circle_24"
    app:tint="#353535" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Personal Info"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/personalInfoProgress"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/personalInfoTab"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/personalInfoTab" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Payment"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/paymentProgressBar"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/personalInfoProgress"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/paymentTab" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Confirmation"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/confirmationTab"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/paymentProgressBar"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/confirmationTab" />

//frameLayout for your fragments
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2">

 </FrameLayout>
 </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now you can increase the progress and you can use Fragments for different pages ie: **Personal Info**, **Payment**, **Confirmation**

Comment: Thanks , its a pretty neat solution .